# How to make lm() output welch t test in R

Tags: r

I've been told and have seen examples where a linear model and t test are basically the same test just that the t test is a specialized linear model with dummy-coded predictors. Is there a way to get the output of `lm` to output the same t values, p values, confidence intervals, and standard error as the normal `t.test` function in r where the default value for the `var.equal` argument is `FALSE`?

For example right now the outputs of lm and t.test are different right now

```
data("mtcars")
#these outputs below give me different values 
summary(lm(mpg ~ am, mtcars))
t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars)
```

What I want is to make `lm` have the same values as the t.test function., which is a Welch t test. How would I do that?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144480/20833 shows how to do Welch's t-test with `lme4::lmer`; with `stats::lm` it is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, there exists a great post on CrossValidated [How are regression, the t-test, and the ANOVA all versions of the general linear model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59047/how-are-regression-the-t-test-and-the-anova-all-versions-of-the-general-linear)
 that gives a lot of background information on the relationship between a *t*-test, linear regression and ANOVA.

In essence, the p-value from a  *t*-test corresponds to the p-value of the slope parameter in a linear model.

In your case, you need to compare

```
t.test(mpg ~ am, mtcars, alternative = "two.sided", var.equal = T)
#
#   Two Sample t-test
#
#data:  mpg by am
#t = -4.1061, df = 30, p-value = 0.000285
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -10.84837  -3.64151
#sample estimates:
#mean in group 0 mean in group 1
#       17.14737        24.39231

fit <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am), mtcars)
summary(fit)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am), data = mtcars)
#
#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
#-9.3923 -3.0923 -0.2974  3.2439  9.5077
#
#Coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)      17.147      1.125  15.247 1.13e-15 ***
#as.factor(am)1    7.245      1.764   4.106 0.000285 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 4.902 on 30 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.3598,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.3385
#F-statistic: 16.86 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 0.000285
```

Note that p-values agree.

Two comments:

1. `as.factor(am)` turns `am` into a categorical variable
2. To match the assumptions of the linear model (where the error term `epsilon ~ N(0, sigma^2)`), we need to use `t.test` with `var.equal = T` which assumes the variance to be the same for measurements from both groups.
3. The difference in the sign of the *t* value comes from the different definition of the reference level of "categorised" `am`.

---

To get the same group means in the linear model, we can remove the intercept

```
lm(mpg ~ as.factor(am) - 1, mtcars)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ as.factor(am) - 1, data = mtcars)
#
#Coefficients:
#as.factor(am)0  as.factor(am)1
#         17.15           24.39
```

Comment: Instead of showing how to do Welch's t-test with `lm` this answer shows how to make `t.test` behave like the test in `summary(lm())` (namely, Student's t-test).

Answer (score 1):

An assumption of linear regression is that the residuals are normally distributed with a mean of 0 and a constant variance. Therefore your t.test and regression summary will have consistent results only if you assume that the variances are equal.